# Random rearrangement of cells of a table

Tags: html, html-table

I have HTML table and the table contains 100 Rows and 2 columns (200 cells). I would like the cells to be rearranged randomly with respect to it's original row AND/OR it's original column.

This is how I would represent 4 pieces of data.

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td> Data1 </td>
           <td> Data2 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> Data 3 </td>
          <td> Data 4 </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using HTML and CSS only. I intend on enter the contents of each cell manually Initially.

The Data's represent Images for a gallery which I'm working on. Kindly suggest another opinion if I shouldn't be using tables for such an arrangement.

Comment: what language you are using?

Comment: rearrange from where, server side script, client side (javascript)?

Comment: If you're open to using JavaScript, look into [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: How are you populating the table?

Comment: Are you open to using Jquery.?

Comment: I'm using HTML and CSS only. I intend on enter the contents of each cell manually.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to be using a table for this kind of goal. However, to do anything randomly without you sitting at your computer rolling a dice and typing in the result, you will need to use some JavaScript. At the bottom of your page, put something like this:

```
<script>
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var randomArrangement = [];

    for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            randomArrangement.push(images.src);
        } else {
            randomArrangement.unshift(images.src);
        }
    }

    for (var j=0; j < images.length; j++)
    {
        images[i].src = randomArrangement[i];
    }
</script>
```

That will give you an array of your image URLs in a random order, and fill each one into the existing images. However, this will be much more effective and efficient if done server-side before the page load.